# Online Genetic Test Repositories

Tags: genetics, test, reference-request, database

I've found out that NCBI's [Genetic Testing Registry](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gtr) database holds quite a large collection of genetic/genomic tests available. However, it is a database where producers/researchers submit their product voluntarily, so it misses many of the current tests.

Is there any other resource, an online repository for current genetic tests (NGS-related preferentially) other than GTR?

Comment: Are you looking for a comprehensive list of all the genetic tests available?

Comment: Yes but specifically genomic tests or tests involving many genes as their target and tests designed for cancer disease. These parameters could be used as a filter in such an exhaustive repository.